# How to include many pages dynamically using ui:include Primefaces?

Tags: primefaces, facelets

I am beginner.

I am doing a project using Primefaces.

I need to include many pages dynamically when triggering the `p:menuitem`.

I already tried but the dynamic pages are not included properly when clicked on `p:menuitem` and that page only show when refresh of the page(browser).

**Sample Code**

```
<p:menu>
    <p:menuitem action="..." value="Page1"/>
    <p:menuitem action="..." value="Page2"/>
    <p:menuitem action="..." value="Page3"/>
</p:menu>       

<p:outputPanel>
    <ui:include src="#{Pages.dynamicaPagesInclude}"/>
</p:outputPanel>
```

I do not know where I did mistake.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

Please, try this:

**index.xhtml**:This file is the "main" page, the page which contains the menu to select the dynamic pages to load.
When you press over the menuItem, the `page` attribute is set to the selected page value. Then, an ajax request invokes to `changePage` method which is in charge to set the page to load. We say to menuItem that we need to `update` the outputPanel which contains the new page load to show it on the browser.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>Test Prime</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form id="formulario">
        <p:menu>
            <p:menuitem value="Page1" actionListener="#{pages.changePage(1)}" update="outputPanel "/>
            <p:menuitem value="Page2" actionListener="#{pages.changePage(2)}" update="outputPanel"/>
        </p:menu>

        <p:outputPanel id="outputPanel">
            <ui:include src="#{pages.dynamicaPagesInclude}" />
        </p:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**page1.xhtml**:Dummy page which represents a new page.

```html
<ui:composition 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h2>PAGE 1</h2>
</ui:composition>
```

**page2.xhtml**:Dummy page which represents a different page.

```html
<ui:composition 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h2>PAGE 2</h2>
</ui:composition>
```

**Pages.java**:This java class is the ManagedBean for controlling the view. It contains a string field called `dynamicaPagesInclude` with the path of the page to load.
The method `changePage` gets the attribute `page` which was set by the menuitem. Depending its value, chooses a page or other.

```java
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;


@ManagedBean
public class Pages {

    private String dynamicaPagesInclude;

    public String getDynamicaPagesInclude() {
        return dynamicaPagesInclude;
    }

    public void setDynamicaPagesInclude(String dynamicaPagesInclude) {
        this.dynamicaPagesInclude = dynamicaPagesInclude;
    }

    public void changePage(int itemSelected ) {
        if (itemSelected == 1) {
            dynamicaPagesInclude = "page1.xhtml";
        } else {
            dynamicaPagesInclude = "page2.xhtml";
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for my English level.

Comment: Miguel, please add some explanation to your answer why you do things you do. That way you learn people to fish instead of just giving them fish ;-)

Comment: Thank you @Kukeltje. I'm going to explain my answer.

Comment: Thanks... Keep in mind that with 'modern' jsf and EL, you can also pass parameters in actionListeners, so `actionListener="#{pages.changePage(1)}"` with a corresponding changePage method like `public void changePage(int page) {...}` works as well. You can also pass the explicit page in string if you want. In the latter case, you do not need to change the bean if you want to add a page in xhtml. A better solution in my opinion. Maybe 'improve' your answer with this.

Comment: @Miguel.. I checked it log file  when I press p:menuitem the bean value(pages) is bind properly.but update is not work properly when i refresh the pages that pages shows successfully...

Comment: @Migul i didt get any error but that pages does not show at the 1st time of click of each p:menuitems