# How to display a new page within an existing main page in primefaces?

Tags: primefaces

i was trying to display a web page within a page in primefaces. There exists a menu, and when the user clicks on a particular menu item i want the content to be displayed within the same page ie within the body of the main page. How can i achieve that?
Earlier i was opening the page in a new tab , il post the sample code here:

```
<p:submenu label="Tools">
                            <p:menuitem
                                onclick="window.open('https://newpage/login.do')"
                                value="New page"></p:menuitem>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ui:include` (`xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"`) to include arbitrary pages which are even dynamically calculable:

```
<ui:include src="#{bean.page}"/>
```

Comment: i am sorry, i dint understand. When i click the menu item ie: New page, the new page webpage must open within the main page itself.

Comment: You need to have a include in your page and when you click on a menu you have to re-set the included page (the value of `bean.page`). Another possibility is that you invent a template including the navigation and every XHTML page uses the template.

Comment: You can try something like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30880889/how-to-include-many-pages-dynamically-using-uiinclude-primefaces/30885560#30885560